# Is there a more efficient method than transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

```
insert into table1 ...;
update table2 set count=count+1;
```

The above inserts something into `table1`, and if it succeeds, updates the `count` field of `table2`.

Of course this kind of thing can be handled by transactions, but transactions need to lock the table, which will be not efficient in a high concurrent system. And it can be even worse if you need to update multiple tables in that transaction.

What's your solution?

I'm using PHP, and I implement transactions this way:

```
mysql_query('begin');

mysql_query($statement1);

mysql_query($statement2);
...
mysql_query('commit');
```

So it looks like all tables referred in those `$statement` will be locked?

Answer (score 3):

A transaction (which in context of `MySQL` assumes `InnoDB`) will not need to lock the whole table.

The `INSERT` will lock the individual row without gap locks.

The `UPDATE` will not lock any gaps too if you provide an equality or `IN` condition on an indexed field in the `WHERE` clause.

This means that with a properly indexed table, `INSERTs` will not block each other, while the `UPDATEs` will only block each other if they affect the same row.

The `UPDATE` will of course lock the individual row it affects, but since it is the last operation in your transaction, the lock will be lifted immediately after the operation is commited.

The locking itself is in fact required so that two concurrent updates will increment the counts sequentially.

Comment: INSERTs may not block each other with row-locks, but they can still contend with locks on the indexes in the table, and indeed, deadlock with one another. I have seen it.

Comment: `@MarkR`: you're right, and that's why I specifically mentioned "properly indexed table". Here's a question about the problem you're talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974890/mysql-stored-procedure-causing-problems

Answer (score 2):

Use InnoDB storage engine.  It is row level locking instead of MyISAM which is table level locking.

Comment: Or you could switch to Oracle which (under most cases) performs NO locking. :)

Comment: `@LBushkin`: any `DML` operation on a permanent table in `Oracle` locks the affected rows until the end of transaction.

Comment: Oracle will lock rows where relevant - it is necessary to obtain correct transactional behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Transactions will not necessarily request a lock for the whole table.

In addition, InnoDB supports various translation isolation levels using different locking strategies. You may want to check:

- [MySQL: SET TRANSACTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html)
- [MySQL Transactions, Part II - Transaction Isolation Levels](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3393161/MySQL-Transactions-Part-II---Transaction-Isolation-Levels.htm)

Answer (score 1):

these looks more like a "Triggers" job to me. onInsert do something.

Comment: Which version of MySQL has a stable trigger implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are great to ensure a "all or nothing" behavior -- even if there is a high load or high concurrency in your system, you shouldn't stop using transactions, at least if you need your data to stay coherent !

*(And transactions will not necessarily lock the whole table(s))*

Answer (score 0):

If speed were of the absolute essence, I might be tempted to cache the update count in memory (using thread-safe code) and only write it back to the database periodically.  I would certainly use a transaction when I did so.  The downside to this is that you would need to be willing to treat the count as only approximate.  If you needed it to be absolutely correct for an operation, then it would need to be recalculated, again within a transaction.

As others have pointed out, using a database that supports row-level locking and simply using an explicit (or implicit via a trigger) transaction is probably easier.  It's definitely more accurate and safer.